# FreeCodeCamp: checking for palindromes

Tags: javascript

This is my first question, so I apologize if this isn't formatted correctly or placed in the proper area.

I just completed the FreeCodeCamp checking for palindromes challenge.  I can't help but think my solution was very inelegant.

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var cleanString = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
  var lowerCleanString = cleanString.toLowerCase();
  var lowerArr = lowerCleanString.split('');
  var reverseArr = lowerArr.reverse();
  var joinedArr = reverseArr.join('');
  if (joinedArr === lowerCleanString) {
    return true;
  }
  // Good luck!
  else {
   return false;
  }
}
```

I know it worked, but is it possible to do some of these steps together or in a cleaner way?

Comment: use built-in javascript Array and String methods. 
`(e => e == e.split('').reverse().join(''))`

Comment: Code `return joinedArr === lowerCleanString` Instead of the `if else`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple function to check for palindromes

```
function checkPalindrome(palindrome) {
return palindrome == palindrome.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var newstr = str.replace(/[\W_]/g,'').toLowerCase();  

    if(newstr === newstr.split('').reverse().join('')){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

palindrome("five|\_/|four");
```

You can use many methods in one row like I've used them .It's more simple :)
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I really like the answers comparing the string to a `string.split('').reverse().join('')` version of itself.  I didn't think about that.  Forgot about the `.reverse()` function.  I ended up processing the string and splitting it out into an array and then using a double counter for the loop to compare the first and last items in the array.  Was kinda fun to learn how to do that, but I like the `.reverse()` function use better.

In case someone is curious about the for loop I used ...

```
for(let i = 0, j = arr.length-1; i < j; i++, j--) {  
  if (arr[i] !== arr[j]) {
    return false;
  }
}
```